# Solving a recurrence using the Master Theorem where $f(n) = log(\log n)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I have the recurrence
$$T(n) = 3\,T(n/2) + \log(\log n)$$
I take $a = 3$, $b = 2$ and $f(n) = \log(\log n)$. I also have $\log_2 3 = 1.585$.

I'm not sure how to approach a log inside of a log. Would you solve this the same way you would if $f(n) = n\log n$?

Comment: You have $(\forall \varepsilon > 0) \log(\log(n)) = O(n^\varepsilon)$. In particular $\log(\log(n)) = O(n)$. Hence $\log(\log(n)) = O(n^c)$ where $c<\log_b(a)$ and so you have case 1 of the master theorem. (Here I am following Wikipedia's notation). You do get the same answer as you would if $f(n) = n \log n$, since $\log_2(3) > 1$.

Comment: @Ian Thank you. Allow me to ask a stupid question. I'm really slow so I'm still trying to understand some things. When we're looking for c, we're just looking for the exponent in f(n)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on Ian's hint, consider the following two recurrences:
$$
\begin{align*}
U(n) &= 3U(n/2) + n \\
L(n) &= 3L(n/2)
\end{align*}
$$
We also use the same base cases for $U(n),L(n)$ as for $T(n)$. Easy induction shows that $L(n) \leq T(n) \leq U(n)$. The Master theorem shows that $L(n) = \Omega(n^{\log_23})$ and $U(n) = O(n^{\log_23})$, so we conclude that $T(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_23})$.